# "At least one output file must be specified" error when using concat protocol

Tags: ffmpeg, concatenation, aac

I've been attempting to concatenate all the `.aac` files in a directory to make one output `.aac`. Here is the command I'm using:

```
ffmpeg -i concat:1.aac|2.aac|3.aac -c copy output.aac
```

When I try to execute this command in the directory, I get this error:

```
At least one output file must be specified
```

I have no idea where I went wrong, but any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: The weird thing here is that I've used the exact same command for all the .ts files in my directory and it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add quotes:

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:1.aac|2.aac|3.aac" -c copy output.aac
```

Comment: The command works, but I'm having an issue with the output now. The file is much larger than the total length of all segments combined. It should be around 9 1/2 minutes long, but its producing an output of 15 minutes. Any clue why?

Comment: @DataMsc Should be asked as a new question because it is a completely different problem/topic. This Q/A is only about the `At least one output file must be specified` error when using the concat protocol.